# How do I manage 401K Contribution limits across multiple sources of income?

Tags: 401k, solo-401k

I have an employer sponsored 401K plan where my employer matches up to a certain limit. I max out at 19.5K and my employer pays about 7.5K which works out to be 27K total.

Now I also perform independent consulting and make about 30K per year. All this income is reported in a 1099-NEC (used to be 1099-MISC) form.

Now I am planning to open a separate solo 401K to put some money from this venture. Based on my research I can put another 19.5K + 25% of my adjusted earned income (say that works out be 20% which is 6K) = 25.5K

My question is as long as the 27K + 25.5K = 52.5K total remains under the 58K total 401k contribution limit, I am good to go correct? Are there other thing for me to keep in mind when I try to max out my solo 401k.

Another question I had is do the calculations change if I go for a Roth 401k or is it the same except of course I will still pay taxes on the 25.5K.

Thanks for any responses in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- *Employee* traditional and Roth contributions are capped at 19.5k *across all plans* (assuming you're under 50 years old)
- Each *plan's* total employee (traditional, Roth, and after-tax) and employer contributions are capped at 58k

Since you maxed out your employee contribution at your employer plan, you met the 19.5k cap already and may not make any more *employee* traditional and Roth contributions to *any* plan.

Hence, for your individual 401(k), you may only make an *employer* contribution (traditional only) of 20% of your self-employed net income *minus the employer portion of your self-employment tax*, so 30k * (1 - 92.35% * 7.65%) * 20% = 5576. NB: your employer contribution is limited to 20%, *not 25%,* since the employer portion of your self-employment tax circularly determines your net income and hence your employer contribution limit (see the [Rate Table for Self-Employed in Publication 560](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p560#en_US_2020_publink10009065)).

I've found [this calculator](https://obliviousinvestor.com/solo-401k-contribution-calculator/) to be very useful.

Comment: If your individual 401(k) plan allows after-tax employee contributions (which doesn't seem possible with the major brokerages' individual 401(k) offerings), you may contribute an after-tax employee contribution of 22304, which would max out your total employee+employer contribution for the individual 401(k) plan to the lesser of 58k or your net earnings from self-employment, viz. 30k * (1 - 92.35% * 7.65%) = 27880.

Comment: But I'm 90% sure about the after-tax employee contribution ... Confirmation or correction welcome :)

Comment: Thanks for plugging a major gap in my understanding - i.e. my contribution is pegged at 19.5K across all channels. If that is the case, then I guess I could simply live with a SEP IRA since I will max my 401K contribution at my regular day job anyway.